# storing run time data to CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am trying to store my run time output into a CSV file. It stores only one data, but I want to store all of them.

My code,

```
path = self.paths[src][dst]
next_hop = path[path.index(dpid) + 1]
out_port = self.network[dpid][next_hop]['port']

print("path: ", path)
writer=csv.writer(open('pth.csv','wb'))
writer.writerow([path]);
```

The output is,

```
['62:61:5f:80:dc:ca', 5, 4, 1, '46:22:26:36:96:48']
['62:61:5f:80:dc:ca', 5, 4, 1, '46:22:26:36:96:48']
['62:61:5f:80:dc:ca', 5, 4, 1, '46:22:26:36:96:48']
['62:61:5f:80:dc:ca', 5, 4, 1, '46:22:26:36:96:48']
['62:61:5f:80:dc:ca', 5, 4, 1, '46:22:26:36:96:48']
['46:22:26:36:96:48', 1, 4, 5, '62:61:5f:80:dc:ca']
['46:22:26:36:96:48', 1, 4, 5, '62:61:5f:80:dc:ca']
['46:22:26:36:96:48', 1, 4, 5, '62:61:5f:80:dc:ca']
```

It would be helpful if you could give a hint

Comment: I see multiple different lines in the output. Please explain how this is only "one data" and what "all of them" would look like.

Comment: The multiple different lines are the actual output. But in the file, it stores only the last line data.

Answer (score 1):

> But in the file, it stores only the last line data.

It's probably because of this:

```
open('pth.csv','wb')
```

By using `w`, you truncate the file, meaning it will overwrite the previous contents.
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open:

> The most commonly-used values of mode are `'r'` for reading, `'w'` for
>   writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and `'a'` for
>   appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to
>   the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).

See also related [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python).

Try using `a`:

```
open('pth.csv','ab')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But it also keeps the previous data. is it possible to keep the current data only?

Comment: @joes Hmm.. I don't understand what you mean.. You can either keep appending (`a`) or always overwrite what's already there (`w`). Other than that, you'll have to maybe use some other [file seeking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) methods to "restart" the file pointer. Something like, use `a` until you've written 10 rows. Then seek back to the start, then write the next 10 rows (overwriting the "previous" data).

Comment: @joes ..or maybe keep appending (`a`) the "current data", then for a new data set, `open` a new file or move/rename the current file. It's quite unclear what you want, since all you asked is "_but I want to store all of them_".